# Finding duplicate value and taking difference with other values with Excel/SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012

I have got a very strange problem. I have lot of data with columns of dates, ID column etc. I want to take the difference of time of 2 dates (where dates are reported as 7/16/2017 18:42) in both columns. At first instance, it looks easy to take simple difference but problem here is ID column. In ID column, there are lot of IDs where IDs are duplicate also. So below are the conditions:

1. Take difference of date and time where first row of ID. Like A2-B2
2. When same ID comes again, take the difference of Date then difference would be like B2-A3. But ID should be from same group.

Below are the rows:

```
ID  Date 1  Date 2
5AB80D3A    7/10/2017 14:16 7/14/2017 11:38
5AB80D3A    7/14/2017 11:38 7/14/2017 12:48
5AB80D3A    7/14/2017 13:00 7/14/2017 19:09
5AB80D3A    7/14/2017 19:09 7/14/2017 21:09
5AB80D      7/14/2017 19:09 7/14/2017 21:09
5AB80D      7/14/2017 19:09 7/14/2017 21:09
5AB80A      7/14/2017 19:09 7/14/2017 21:09
```

If this can be done in excel/SQL, it will be helpful. Thanks in advance for your guidance.

Comment: If you are not using MySQL, remove the tag.  Otherwise the question is misleading.

Comment: I am fetching data from SQL query. So if I can build this syntex in query then also it works.

Comment: what sql server are you using?

Comment: SQL server 2012

Comment: So you want the max in column B minus the min in column A where the IDs are the same?

Comment: Nope. There will be duplicate IDs. It will be ordered by IDs. When first row of any ID comes then I need to take difference of C2-B2 as given in example. When I check row A3, ID is duplicate but A2 row has the same ID. So in that case difference would be B4 -C3. If I consider row A6 (including header of ID mentioned as row A1) ID number comes first time.So difference would be C6-B6. For A7 it would be B8-C7 but condition is that B8 must have same ID as in A7.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the below query , it might guides you to do what you want.

```
 ;with
Testdata as
(select Id,Date1 ,Date2 
,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Id order by Date1) rowNumber
from Q1
)
select currentData.ID,currentData.Date1,currentData.Date2
,case when currentData.rowNumber=1 then datediff(MINUTE,currentData.Date1,currentData.Date2) else datediff(MINUTE,currentData.Date1,prevData.Date2) End Diffs  
from testData currentData 
left join Testdata prevData on currentData.ID=prevData.ID and currentData.rowNumber=prevData.rowNumber+1
```

## Edit

after reviwing your comments I get the following query , hope it helps you

```
 ;with
Testdata as
(select Id,Date1 ,Date2 
 ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Id order by Date1) rowNumber
 from Q1
)
select currentData.ID,currentData.Date1,currentData.Date2
,case when currentData.rowNumber=1 then datediff(MINUTE,currentData.Date1,currentData.Date2) else datediff(MINUTE,currentData.Date2,nextData.Date1) End Diffs  
from testData currentData 
left join Testdata nextData on currentData.ID=nextData.ID and currentData.rowNumber=nextData.rowNumber-1
```

## Edit2 (using row_number & order by Date1 Descending to get the last row for every ID)

```
 ;with
Testdata as
(select Id,Date1 ,Date2 
 ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Id order by Date1) rowNumber
 ,ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by Id order by Date2) rowNumberDesc
 from Q1
)
 select currentData.ID,currentData.Date1,currentData.Date2
 ,case when currentData.rowNumber=1 or currentData.rowNumberDesc=1  then datediff(MINUTE,currentData.Date1,currentData.Date2) else datediff(MINUTE,currentData.Date2,nextData.Date1) End Diffs  
 from testData currentData 
 left join Testdata nextData on currentData.ID=nextData.ID and currentData.rowNumber=nextData.rowNumber-1
```

Comment: I tested it, it's working , you have to post some sample data with the result you want to get.

Comment: ID Date 1  Date 2 Diff
5AB80D3A 7/10/2017 14:16 7/14/2017 11:38 21:22
5AB80D3A 7/14/2017 11:38 7/14/2017 12:48 0:00
5AB80D3A                     7/14/2017 13:00 7/14/2017 19:09 0:12
5AB80D3A                     7/14/2017 19:09 7/14/2017 21:09 0:00
5AB80D                             7/15/2017 19:09 7/15/2017 23:09 22:00
5AB80D                             7/16/2017 19:09 7/16/2017 21:09 20:00
5AB80A                             7/17/2017 19:09 7/17/2017 21:09 22:00

Comment: Last columns is difference column. Where first row give difference of date 1 and 2 and second row onwards, it gives difference of date1 of current row and Date 2 of previous row.

Comment: I thought that you want the difference between date1 and date2 in the first record, only , then in the second row  get the difference between the date2 in the previous and date1 in the second row, and so on.

Comment: I didn't understand the data in diff column in your comment.

Comment: There are only 3 columns in my reference data. ID, Date 1 in format of MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS and DATE 2 with same format.

Comment: One more question that for last row, of any ID I want the difference of same column DATE 1 and DATE 2

Comment: I've edited the query to get the difference in the last column between the same date1 & Date 2